# C#: Error. Not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#, loops, search

I'm working on a project in C# and I have created the following function:

```
static bool detectIfRepeated(OleDbConnection cnx, String username)
{
    DataTable res = new DataTable();
    OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM UserPassword", cnx);
    adp.Fill(res);

    int i = 0;
    bool found = false;
    String user = Convert.ToString(res.Rows[i]["User"]);
    while (i < res.Rows.Count && !found)
    {
        if (user == username)
        {
            found = true;
            MessageBox.Show("The username is already taken. Choose a different one.");
            return true;
        }
        else
            i++;
    }
    if (!found)
        return false;
}
```

However, I don't know why (I've been trying to look for the mistake for one hour) I'm getting the error: **Not all code paths return a value.**

I can't see why not, the program navigates on the list if it finds that usernames are the same it returns true; if it has not find any coincidence after the whole loop it returns false.

Please can anyone help me find it? I'm sure it has to be a silly mistake but I am getting crazy...

Thank you so much!!

Comment: I'm not able to see the reason for the "found" variable in this code.
When you initiate it, you initiate it to false, the only time you change it is right before you return true, and then you're not checking against it.

Also, the only time you're checking the value of found is when you're outside the loop, but then it's guaranteed to be false (since the only place you change it on is right before a return)

So, what I'm trying to say is that you could remove the found variable and the lines that change or check it and your code would do the exact same thing (without the compiler complaining)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just return the variable **found** that you have declared

```
  static bool detectIfRepeated(OleDbConnection cnx, String username)
    {
        DataTable res = new DataTable();
        OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM UserPassword", cnx);
        adp.Fill(res);

        int i = 0;
        bool found = false;
        String user = Convert.ToString(res.Rows[i]["User"]);
        while (i < res.Rows.Count && !found)
        {
            if (user == username)
            {
                found = true;
                MessageBox.Show("The username is already taken. Choose a different one.");

            }
            else
                i++;
        }
        return found
    }
```

Comment: My downvote was firstly because it was a dump of code with no explanation, and secondly, it has at least one syntax error. I was attempting to add a comment about that, but couldn't, because you then deleted your answer. You did now edit your answer to provide a minimal explanation, but it's an explanation that's useful for the OP to understand what's wrong with the original code.

Comment: @hvd I never deleted my answer, actually it took some time to get posted since was posting from a mobile device

Comment: @Sajeetharan That's odd. The error SO gave me when I attempted to comment was the exact message given when attempting to comment on a deleted answer. Sorry about that, then.

Answer (score 3):

Well, not all code paths return a value. That says all. If `found` is true you don't return anything.

Why don't you do

```
return found;
```

instead of

```
   if (!found)
            return false;
```

Comment: The only code path in which `found` is set to `true` causes `return true;` to be executed. There is no code path that doesn't return a value. The only problem is the compiler doesn't see that.

Comment: Thanks so much it was that! I knew it would be a little mistake... Great!

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the compiler doesn't "think" like you do and don't see how your code would work.

What you could do to trick the emulator (if you don't want to return "found") could be to throw an error if is found and you're outside the while loop.

```
if(!found)
  return false;
else
  throw new Exception();
```

But since you only seems to be returning the value of found anyway it does sound like the simplest, more clean solution would be to simply return found (since you already know that it will be false at that position).

That would also be something the compiler would accept.